# multi Picklist values in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, multi-select

i am new to lwc. I am stuck with  assigning values to multi picklist in Lwc like that
 `let applicationnNameValues= 'A;B';`. I am using standard `createRecord` method. when i remove that value `applicationnNameValues` then  record insert successfully. The Code is below

```
  createCase(event) {
       let applicationnNameValues = 'A;B'
        this.validateFields();
     
       if(this.validatecheckForSave){
           return
       }
       
       console.log('call 2');
        try {
            // Creating mapping of fields of Account with values
            var fields = {
                'Customer_s_Name__c': this.valCustomerName, 'Status': 'new',
                'Follow_Up_Callback_Required__c': this.valueFollowUpCallBack,
                'Notification_Source__c': this.valueNoticationSource,
                'Date_of_Communication__c': this.valDateTime,
                'Reason_of_Communication__c': this.valueReasonOfComm,
                'Description': 'testing....',
                'RecordTypeId': '0125C000000d6TUQAY',
                'Customer_s_Callback_Number__c': this.valCustomerCallbackNumber,
                'Customer_s_Email_Address__c': this.valCustomerEmailAddress,
                'Primary_Student_Name__c': this.valPrimaryStudentName,
                'Are_there_siblings__c': this.valueSiblings,
                'Do_you_need_support_from_the_Applicati__c': this.valApplicationCo,

               /************below code cause error******/

               'Application_Name__c': applicationnNameValues, 

                'Service_Type__c': this.valServiceType,
                'Exceptional_Services__c': this.valExceptionalService,
                'Type_of_Change_of_Service__c': this.valTypeOfServiceChg,
                'Transportation_Supervision_Authorization__c': this.valtSupervisionAuthorizationForm,
                'Level_of_Disruption__c': this.vallevelDisruption,
            };

            // Record details to pass to create method with api name of Object.
            var objRecordInput = { 'apiName': 'Case', fields };
            // LDS method to create record.


            createRecord(objRecordInput).then(response => {
                this.showLoading = false;
                const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Record Created successfully',
                    variant: 'success'


                });
                dispatchEvent(toastEvent);

                //event.preventDefault();
               /* let componentDef = {
                    componentDef: "c:caseTypeBannerComponent",
                    attributes: {
                        label: 'Go to Home'
                    }
                };
                let encodedComponentDef = btoa(JSON.stringify(componentDef));
                this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                    type: 'standard__webPage',
                    attributes: {
                        url: '/one/one.app#' + encodedComponentDef
                    }
                });
                */
                const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent("screen1event",{bubbles:true,composed:true});
                this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);

            }).catch(error => {
                console.log('error>>>1' ,error);
                const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'Record Created failed',
                    variant: 'error'
               

                });
                dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('error>>>2' ,e);
        }
    
}
```

`Application_Name__c` is multi pick list  field [image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be `['A','B']`, as in a proper array.

Comment: still error.....Value for field 'Application_Name__c' in object 'C…ST' should be a String but instead is a String[].

Comment: Are you sure the cause of error is Multi-select picklist? Check the line `var objRecordInput = { 'apiName': 'Case', fields };` >>>> Shouldn't this be `var objRecordInput = { 'apiName': 'Case', 'fields': fields };`? Ideally, i would recommend you make use of [generateRecordInputForCreate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_generate_record_input_create)

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the field configuration ? Are you sure you send api value of picklist option ? Do you have the rights to create the record / write this field / values are allowed for this record type ?

@arut : the two pieces of JS you gave produce the exact same result, JS shortcut.

Comment: You are right @Bartheleway. I should have checked it before posting.

Comment: Could you make an answer with the solution to help next person which consult this ?